# Vue2: Avoid mutating a prop directly inside component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm gettig this "Avoid mutating a prop directly", when checking if the persons input should get an invalid class because its empty.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="srx">
  <input type="number" name="persons" id="persons" value="" v-model="persons" :class="{invalid: !persons}">

</script>


<div id="app">
  {{stepText}}
  <sr-el :persons="1"></sr-el>

  <button v-if="currentStep > 1" type="button" v-on:click="previous()">prev</button>
  <button v-if="currentStep < 6" type="button" :disabled="currentStepIsValid()" v-on:click="next()">
    next</button>
</div>

Vue.component('sr-el', {
  template: '#srx',
  props: ['persons'],
})


var App = window.App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    persons: '1'
    currentStep: 1,
  },
  methods: {
    currentStepIsValid: function() {

      if (this.currentStep == 1) {
        this.stepText = "Step 1;
        return !(this.persons > 0);
      }

    },
    previous: function() {
      this.currentStep = this.currentStep - 1;
      // prev slide
    },

    next: function() {
      this.currentStep = this.currentStep + 1;
      // next slide

    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that warning because you are binding `persons` to the input in the template via `v-model`. Changing the input's value will thus change the value of `persons`, which means the prop is getting mutated directly in your `sr-el` component.

You should set a new property equal to `persons` and pass that to `v-model` instead:

```
Vue.component('sr-el', {
  template: '#srx',
  props: ['persons'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      inputVal: this.persons,
    }
  }
})
```

```
<input v-model="inputVal" ... />
```

Comment: OK, but how can i then use the srx element dynamically for other elements then "persons"?

Comment: Pass a different variable as the `persons` property: https://jsfiddle.net/gsxzz7Ls/1/

Comment: But the input elements have the same ids and names. When passing them via POST they have to have individual names.

Comment: pass in a `name` property and bind that to the `name` and `id` attributes of the input: https://jsfiddle.net/3a23bbLw/

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks!

Comment: looks like thats not working with the type attrib: https://jsfiddle.net/u8ncfdvn/

Comment: It is working, the first is a number type and the second is a text type

Comment: Yes, but it dropping an template compiling error in the console.

Comment: Okay, yeah so you'll want to use `v-if` statements like the message says. Anyways, all of this is very outside the scope of the original question. If you have a new question, please post it.